# How to create a new file in a folder on the desktop with AppleScript?

Tags: file, applescript, directory, desktop

I'm trying to create a file in a folder on my desktop using AppleScript.

```
set blankPage to (((path to desktop) as string) & "text.txt")
```

I know `path to desktop` point to the desktop, but how do I get it to point into a folder on the desktop ex. ("Text files")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the folder exists, you get the path to it with Finder:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set blankPage to (folder "Text files" of (path to desktop) as text) & ¬
        "text.txt" as alias
end tell
```

To make an empty text file you can use the Finder like this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set blankPage to make new file at folder "Text files" of (path to desktop) ¬
        with properties {name:"text.txt"}
end tell
```

Using the shell is a faster way:

```
do shell script "> $HOME'/Desktop/Text files/text.txt'"
```

Comment: How to specify a folder different from desktop?

Answer (score 1):

this will add context menu to file/folder to create empty text file, (if file is present, it will try to create untitled (1).txt, etc)

1. open Atomator
2. menu File - new
3. service receives dropdown: 'files or folders', in 'Finder.app'
4. next to Actions in Variables lookup type 'applescript'
5. find and dbl click or drag to right window 'Run AppleScript'
6. in window paste, save as 'New Text File'

> ```
> tell application "Finder"
>   set fname to "untitled.txt"
>   set i to 0
>   repeat while i < 999
>   if i > 0 then
>     set fname to "untitled (" & i & ").txt"
>   end if
>   if not (file (target of Finder window 1 as string & fname) exists) then
>       tell application "Finder" to make new file at (the target of the front window) as alias with properties {name:fname}
>       set i to 1000
>       return
>   end if
>   set i to i + 1
>   end repeat
> end tell
> ```

Comment: there is also simple Finder extra option in https://www.groovypost.com/howto/quickly-create-new-blank-text-file-windows-mac-linux/